# VueJS add remove class on click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a "menu" with colors, and when the user click one of the div's, it should add an active class, and remove all other active classes from the others div... How do I do this in VUE?

```
<div class="choose-color__primary" style="width:400px">
                            <div class="light" v-on:click="selectColor($event)" :style="{'background-color': LightenDarkenColor(colors.primaryColor, 30)}"></div>
                            <div class="light" v-on:click="selectColor($event)" :style="{'background-color': LightenDarkenColor(colors.primaryColor, 15)}"></div>
                            <div class="light" v-on:click="selectColor($event)" :style="{'background-color': LightenDarkenColor(colors.primaryColor, 0)}"></div> <!-- This is the color the user has chosen from color wheel -->
                            <div class="dark" v-on:click="selectColor($event)" :style="{'background-color': LightenDarkenColor(colors.primaryColor, -15)}"></div>
                            <div class="dark" v-on:click="selectColor($event)" :style="{'background-color': LightenDarkenColor(colors.primaryColor, -30)}"></div>
                        </div>
```

I know that i in my selectColor() function could do something like:

```
event.target.parentNode.classList.remove("active");
            event.target.className = "active";
```

However, just thought there was a better way in VUE than manipulating the DOM directly this this?

Comment: You can use :class vue directive. Perhaps you need to refactor code. Show divs by v-for from array : [{class: 'light|dark', active: true|false: background: number}]

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this and swap out the color strings for objects to also get the light and dark class in there

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#chooser',
  data: () => ({
    // generate the array as you want
    colors: [
      'green', '#000', '#123'
    ],
    activeColor: ''
  })
 })
```

```css
.colors > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.active {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="chooser">
  <div class="choose-color__primary colors" style="width:400px">
      <div 
        v-for="color in colors" 
        @click="activeColor = color" 
        :style="{'background-color': color}"
        :class="{active: color === activeColor}"
       ></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What if complicated logic has to be fullfilled in order to determine wether to change the class or not or to change it depending on the current state in different ways...?